How to reset vnstat like I had never installed it?
I have installed vnstat on Arch Linux. It works perfectly. Now I need to measure traffic from a special date and wanna reset vnstat. I have stopped its service:
sudo systemctl stop vnstat

and run:
vnstat -r

and after starting the service I see nothing happened.
How to reset its database so all traffic gets zero?

I'll make few assumptions:

the vnStat version being used is 2.x (can be verified with vnstat --version)
the default database directory hasn't been changed

With assumption 1, vnstat -r should have resulted in Unknown parameter "-r". Use --help for help. output but on the other hand Arch shouldn't have any 1.x versions available.
With those assumptions, the way to fully reset vnStat to contain no past data is simply to remove the database while the daemon isn't running:

sudo systemctl stop vnstat - stops the service
sudo rm -f /var/lib/vnstat/vnstat.db - removes the database
sudo systemctl start vnstat - starts the service again
systemctl status vnstat - should show that the service has started without errors and has populated the database with available interfaces
wait for 5 minutes (that's the default database write interval)
vnstat should now show data

